# Can JSON-LD be used to auto update a merchant feed?

Tags: feed, schema.org, json-ld, google-product-search

Will Google read Schema.org markup in the form of JSON-LD to automatically update a product feed?

[It says that it uses Microdata](https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/3246284) but it doesn’t say whether or not it will look at JSON-LD when updating the feed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For using Automatic Item Update you must set the microdata from
>   schema.org in your HTML, but I am afraid you won't be able to use
>   JSON-LD.
>
> Also, keep in mind that with the Automatic Item Update you won't need
>   to update your feed anymore, it is just for cases where the
>   price/availability of the product in the landing page has changed but
>   you haven't updated yet your feed, but you still need to provide feed
>   with accurate information.

[Answer](http://muse.j-26.com/1REuiAt) provided by [KathleenG](http://muse.j-26.com/1Hlm7HJ), an adwords community manager.